# firebase messaging not showing notification when the app is in foreground

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

My flutter app isn't showing notifications when the app is running in the foreground. Works fine when it's in the background or closed. this is my current code, Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm using an old firebase messaging version because I've started this project a long time ago and didn't got time to complete it.  Thank you

```
 void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
  }

  if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
  }
}

final Map<String, Item> _items = <String, Item>{};
Item _itemForMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  final dynamic data = message['data'] ?? message;
  final String itemId = data['id'];
  final Item item = _items.putIfAbsent(itemId, () => Item(itemId: itemId))
    ..status = data['status'];
  return item;
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _homeScreenText = "Waiting for token...";
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Widget _buildDialog(BuildContext context, Item item) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Text("Item ${item.itemId} has been updated"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('CLOSE'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, false);
          },
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('SHOW'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, true);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _showItemDialog(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => _buildDialog(context, _itemForMessage(message)),
    ).then((bool shouldNavigate) {
      if (shouldNavigate == true) {
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      }
    });
  }

  void _navigateToItemDetail(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    final Item item = _itemForMessage(message);
    // Clear away dialogs
    Navigator.popUntil(context, (Route<dynamic> route) => route is PageRoute);
    if (!item.route.isCurrent) {
      Navigator.push(context, item.route);
    }
  }

  initializeFCM() async {
    final _permissionGranted =
        await _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
    if (_permissionGranted == null || _permissionGranted == true) {
      _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onMessage: $message");
          showToastSuccess("You got a new Order!");

          //  HighOrderArea();
          _showItemDialog(message);
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onLaunch: $message");
          _navigateToItemDetail(message);
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onResume: $message");
          _navigateToItemDetail(message);
        },
      );
    }

    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) async {
      assert(token != null);

      var sendToken = await sendNotiTokenApi(token.toString());
      print("tokenadichh");
      print(sendToken);
      setState(() {
        _homeScreenText = "Push Messaging token: $token";
      });
      print(_homeScreenText);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeFCM();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }

  void showNotification(message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'com.dfa.flutterchatdemo'
          : 'com.duytq.flutterchatdemo',
      'Flutter chat demo',
      'your channel description',
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    print(message);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, message['title'].toString(),
        message['body'].toString(), platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: json.encode(message));
  }

  void configLocalNotification() {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        new AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_stat_name');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        iOS: initializationSettingsIOS, android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `onMessage` to include your `showNotification` method.

`onMessage` is called when the app receives an FCM notification in the foreground.

The `showNotification` method contains the code to use the `flutter_local_notifications` plugin to show the notification locally.

```dart
onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {    
  showNotification(message);
  _showItemDialog(message);
},
```

Also ensure to initialize the `flutter_local_notifications` plugin.

Your `configLocalNotification()` method already contains this.

Add it in the `initState` like this:

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeFCM();
    configLocalNotification();
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting notifications on the status bar. But I'm not getting alert dialog while sending notifications.

Comment: Yeah, you need to include `_showItemDialog(message);` in the `onMessage` callback. I've included it in the answer now.

Comment: I've already called that function in onmessage. but it's not working. Alert dialog is not coming.

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console? Also try setting a breakpoint in the `onMessage` callback and see what fires.

Comment: No, there are no errors in the console. I'm getting that print and toast while sending notification. But no alert dialog. am i done it right?

Comment: Include the code for `showToastSuccess()` and also add a print statement in the `_showItemDialog()` method to see if it runs.

Comment: as you told I printed something inside _showItemDialog() and it's printing in the console. don't know why alert dialog isn't showing